# Wordthumb error on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the following error when trying to display an image on my new wordpress site:

```
A WordThumb error has occured

The following error(s) occured:
Could not get a lock for writing.


Query String : src=http://xxxx.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Bamboo-Logo.png&w=300&h=200
WordThumb version : 1.07
```

I am using Themify with the Basic theme installed.  The image is visible within the Wordpress admin page but not on the site.

It looks as though some kind of image resizing plugin called Wordthumb is being used - and that this is where the problem lies.

The image has been uploaded into the Wordpress media library.

Comment: Is the image external? If so, see [this page](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/08/timthumb-part-2-external-websites/). Else, see [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/timthumb-lockfile-error).

Comment: It is an internal image (i.e. is in the wordpress media library).  I followed that link but no one seemed to give a definitive answer.